# How to import all named exports from a file by name without doing the manual way

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Is there a shorthand way to do the following?

```
import { ACTION, ACTION2, ACTION3 } from './actionTypes';
```

when actionTypes looks like:

```
export const ACTION = 'ACTION';
export const ACTION2 = 'ACTION2';
...
```

I also know I could import it like `import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';` but in my opinion it makes the code less pleasant to look at because the actions use will look like `actionTypes.ACTION`. The issue is I have a lot of action types now and don't like the look of the super long import statement required to import a lot by name

Comment: No, there's not. Imports must be explicit.

Comment: You are already doing the 'shorthand'. As @Bergi mentioned, we use imports explicitly.